# Error al hacer length de un string

Tags: java, constructor

```
import fp.util.Checkers;

public class Vivienda {
    private Double superficie;
    private Double precio;
    private Integer numeroHabitaciones;
    private TipoVivienda tipo;
    private String direccion;
    private String distrito;

    public Vivienda(Double superficie, Double precio, Integer numeroHabitaciones, TipoVivienda tipo, String direccion,
            String distrito) {
        Checkers.check("Superficie incorrecta", superficie>0);
        Checkers.check("Precio incorrecto", precio>0);
        Checkers.check("Número de habitaciones incorrecto", numeroHabitaciones>=0);
        Checkers.check("Distrito incorrecto", distrito.length() = 5);
        this.superficie = superficie;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.numeroHabitaciones = numeroHabitaciones;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }
```

Cuando estoy haciendo las restricciones en el constructor (utilizo check(mensaje, valor que debe tomar la pripiedad) de la clase chekers que nos la dan hecha) me da error cuando hago distrito.leng() = 5:  
Multiple markers at this line 
    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable 
    - Line breakpoint:Vivienda [line: 20] - Vivienda(Double, Double, Integer, TipoVivienda,    String,String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas queriendo hacer una asignación en un campo que es para comparar.

Como seguro sabes, en java para comparar necesitas dos signos igual seguidos, de esta forma:

```
a == b
```

siendo:

```
a = b
```

el asignar el valor de b en a (y no es posible asignarle el valor 5 en distrito.length(), y con eso alimentar la función de check que recibe un verdadero para saber si el chequeo es correcto).

En síntesis, te faltó un igual en la comparación de distrito.length() con 5. Tu código para funcionar, debería ser contemplar la comparación así:

```
import fp.util.Checkers;

public class Vivienda {
    private Double superficie;
    private Double precio;
    private Integer numeroHabitaciones;
    private TipoVivienda tipo;
    private String direccion;
    private String distrito;

    public Vivienda(Double superficie, Double precio, Integer numeroHabitaciones, TipoVivienda tipo, String direccion,
            String distrito) {
        Checkers.check("Superficie incorrecta", superficie>0);
        Checkers.check("Precio incorrecto", precio>0);
        Checkers.check("Número de habitaciones incorrecto", numeroHabitaciones>=0);
        Checkers.check("Distrito incorrecto", distrito.length() == 5);
        this.superficie = superficie;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.numeroHabitaciones = numeroHabitaciones;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }
}
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Es verdad!! No me di cuenta, muchisimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Por nada. No olvides el +1 para que sigamos aportando. Mucha suerte!